# How to handle when user clicks on button 100 times (web api services involved)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api2

Recently I faced an interview on WEBAPI. The interviewer asked that when the user clicks continuously on the button, assume that 100 times. In that case, will 100 requests hit the server? How to handle that case on the WEBAPI side.

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases like if you hit the button and it will submit sum datas then definitely yes 100 request hit on the surver every time you click the submit button.

CASE 1 (Handle from back end ) - You can add the validations for not to add the duplicate datas could not enter if it already exist in table from the backend side.

CASE 2 (Handle from front end ) - This type of case you can handle by on button click you can disable the button this will allow user to submit once. this will only allow to submit data once.

- Another way is you can use the setTimeout() to set the intervel like after the button click it will disable and then enable the button after given interval of time.

I will give some example for that you can batter understand.

```js
// demo 1 code - on click disable and enable after settimeout interval

$(document).on('click', '#button_id', function(){
    var element_id = $(this);
  
    $(element_id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $(element_id).html('Loading...');

  setTimeout(function(){
        $(element_id).removeAttr('disabled');
    $(element_id).html('Submit');
    }, 5000); 

});

// demo 1 code - on click disable and cant be enable

$(document).on('click', '#button_click_disable', function(){
    var element_id = $(this);
  $(element_id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

button:disabled,
button[disabled]{
  background: rgba(0, 132, 255, 0.5);
  color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>This is Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <!-- demo 1 -->
  <button id="button_id">Submit</button>
  <br>
  <!-- demo 2 -->
  <button id="button_click_disable">One Click Disable</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```